# How can I get the screen position of the DockTile in OSX?

Tags: macos, position, dock, nsdocktile

I need a window to 'point' to the icon that was clicked on in the dock, similar to the way the context menu has the little callout-arrow pointing to it.  This means I need to get the screen location of the dock, or more accurately the DockTile.  (Yes I could use the mouse coordinates, but that doesn't look as good as it 'moves'.)

Now my thought is to get the associated view (I already have that), then use view-to-screen coordinate conversions, but that's becoming problematic as the x/left and y/top values of the bounding rectangle always say zero.  I know that's because there's a nested hierarchy of views as well.  Problem is I've walked it and always end up hitting a road block.

So thoughts?

Mark

Answer (score 2):

You can get the dock icon positions using the accessibility API, there's some excellent sample code and app from Apple [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#samplecode/UIElementInspector/Introduction/Intro.html).

Comment: Um, that looks like complete overkill!  I dl'd the sample but instantly was overwhelmed.  Plus, that has a dependency on where the mouse is.  I'm more interested in the app that's launching knowing where it's own dock icon is.  That kind of thing.

Comment: I'm looking for that sort of thing too. Did you find anything?

Comment: Nothing yet. Hoping to soon.